# Random Arithmetic overflow with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arithmetic, overflow

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % per i plot

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=5pt]%per riquadrare una parte di testo
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit, arrows.meta, shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} % LATEX and plain TEX when using TikZ
\usetikzlibrary{patterns} % LATEX and plain TEX when using Tik Z

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 4mm with {\node[circle,inner sep=5+rand*.5 cm, draw,black] () at (0,0) {};}}]

\draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above]{Im$[g_{11}(j\omega)]$};
\draw [->] (-4.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right]{Re$[g_{11}(j\omega)]$};

\draw[postaction={decorate},red] (3,0) to [out=-90,in=0] (0,-3);
\draw[postaction={decorate},red] (0,-3) to [out=180,in=-90] (-2.3,0);
\draw[postaction={decorate},red] (-2.3,0) to [out=90,in=120] (0,0);


\draw (-2,1pt) -- (-2,-1pt);
\node[] (-1) at (-2,-.2) {\textbf{-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`
```

Arithmetic overflow in TiKZ?? What is it, and why this error appears only sometimes? How can I solve it?

Comment: I think you can find the answer at page 696 of the TikZ&PGF manual http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf. In case you can try to set another \pgfmathsetseed by choosing a number e.g. \pgfmathsetseed{400} This acts on the rand algorithm.

Comment: No error on my mac.Your code compiles perfectly. You need to avoid some repetitions in the preamble.